# Keycloak Admin Client 20.0.5 : all RoleRepresentation method return an 404 error

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-admin-client

I need to generate automaticaly new group in my realm and try to add global role in this new group

Generating group is ok

Generating role is ok

I get the RoleScopeResource with MY_REALM.groups().group(groupName).roles().realmLevel() and it's ok. A debug print:
RESTEASY004635: Resteasy Client Proxy for : org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RoleScopeResource

but for all method from this object RoleScopeResource (listAll() or add(List.of(RoleRepresentation)) for exemple), I get an 404 error:

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:270) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:240) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:64) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:154) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:115) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76) ~[resteasy-client-4.7.7.Final.jar:4.7.7.Final]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy227.listAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

```
@Override
public void addRealmRoleToGroup(String groupName, String roleName) {
    final RoleRepresentation role = GATEKEEPER_REALM.roles().get(roleName).toRepresentation();
    final RoleScopeResource roleScope = GATEKEEPER_REALM.groups().group(groupName).roles().realmLevel();
    roleScope.add(List.of(role));
}
```

I user spring boot 2.7.8, keycloak and keycloak admin client in 20.0.5
(GateKeeper is the name of my sub-project)

An idea ?